# Syncing Custom Object to a Global Google Calendar

Tags: event, calendar, google

I know that the Lightning Sync will sync users' events with their calendars, but we are wanting to sync a custom object that has a Name, Start Date, End Date and publish this to a shared Google Calendar.

Let me know your ideas about what we can do.

Comment: what ideas have you come up with or considered?

Comment: @KrisGoncalves I ended up using Zapier to bridge the gap for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since we have a subscription through Zapier, I went that route after dinking around I have this fully functional.